# Reported speech grammar error but I couldn't detected it

Tags: grammar, reported-speech

Long time ago I had a assignment which I had to convert a quoted speech to reported speech.
Here's one of the question in my assignment:

```
"I'm going to quit school and get a job".
```

My reported speech answer:

```
Jessica announced that she was going to quit school and got a job.
```

However, according to my teacher, that was incorrect (but I didn't know where the grammar error was), while I thought that was correct.
Any correction and suggestion?

Comment: Why wouldn't your teacher explain it to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Get" is not a present-tense verb, but an infinitive governed by "going to". If it were a finite verb, the sentence would have to parse as "I [[am going to quit school] and [get a job]]", so the second half of the coordination is "I get a job", which is grammatical, but not meaningful in this context.

So, when it is put into reported speech, "get", not being a finite verb, is left unchanged.

**Edited**: it occurs to me that your version "Jessica announced that she was going to quit school and got a job" is perfectly grammatical, but has a different meaning. It parses as "Jessica [announced that she was going to quit school] and [got a job]"; i.e. it says that she did get a job, but not that she announced she was going to.